# mdadm: assembling another array using device removed from active one

Tags: software-raid

In an attempt to enlarge raid1 array on a working machine, I am testing following scenario:

- remove one of two disks
- add bigger disk, resync
- add another bigger disk, resync, grow to raid-devices=3
- "fail" and remove the original, small disk
- "grow" the device back to raid-devices=2
- make a backup raid device using the small disk
- enlarge the main device (now containing two big disks)

Now everything seems to work except one important thing: I am unable to assemble a new md device using the disk "failed" and removed from the original md10 device:

```
mdadm --assemble /dev/md11 /dev/sde3
mdadm: Found some drive for an array that is already active: /dev/md10
mdadm: giving up
```

Is there any way to somehow change the identification of the array on such a removed device?

Answer (score 6):

mdadm is complaining that you're [trying to assemble an array that has a UUID matching one that is already running](https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/utils/mdadm/mdadm/+/mdadm-3.4/Assemble.c#1378). You'll need to change the UUID on the /dev/sde3 superblock as you assemble it using the `--update=uuid` and `--uuid=<newuuid>` parameters. This should tell mdadm to use the UUID you're passing in when comparing to the running arrays.

To find the old UUID, use `mdadm --examine /dev/sde3` and grab the old UUID. You could change it to be unique, or generate a new one.

Your new command would be:
`mdadm --assemble /dev/md11 --update=uuid --uuid=<newuuid> /dev/sde3`

Comment: Could this come from a sudden disconnect of the devices due to a low quality backplane? Your solution is solving my problem but it happens so often I'd like to find out why.